# Flutter : Compare int with list<Map<String,int>>

Tags: arrays, flutter, sorting, object, compare

If anyone is able to help, thank you.

This is the list I want to compare with

```
[{"quote":3,"money":3000}, {"quote":6,"money":7000}, {"quote":8,"money":8000}]
```

On the previous page, the user enters the amount the purchase will be, for example, $3500. If the number exceeds

`3000 then the user needs to present 3 quotes`

`7000 then the user needs to present 6 quotes`

`8000 then the user needs to present 8 quotes`

I am struggling to find a solution to compare the money amount with the list value to get the respective Map value

If anyone has any suggestion. It will be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: first, is the list already sorted or it can be at any order?

Comment: Can be any order

Comment: But if sorting applied..then maybe be sorting by "money"

Comment: Why are you storing [quotes - money - quotes - money - quotes - money] like this? 
Instead if you store it like [{quotes-money}, {quotes-money}, {quotes-money}], it is easier to access an element from list and compare and get the quote amount to the respective money.

Comment: Sorry...Didn't see that... It is sorted as a List<Map<String,int>> but will see why it displayed so weird... Thank you for the mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the data to a more convenient structure

> all the code below will be based on this structure

```
final data = [{"quote":3,"money":3000}, {"quote":6,"money":7000}, {"quote":8,"money":8000},];
```

next step is sorting the data,

> if the data already sorted just like the example you provided you can
> skip this step

I'm gonna use merge sort to sort the data

I changed [Tomic-Riedel's mergeSort implementation](https://gist.github.com/Tomic-Riedel/911c59c43e6082502e6b821f5cf8c904) to match our need.

```
List<Map<String, int>> mergeSort(List<Map<String, int>> array) {

  // Stop recursion if array contains only one element
  if(array.length <= 1) {
    return array;
  }

  // split in the middle of the array
  int splitIndex = array.length ~/ 2;

  // recursively call merge sort on left and right array
  List<Map<String, int>> leftArray = mergeSort(array.sublist(0, splitIndex));
  List<Map<String, int>> rightArray = mergeSort(array.sublist(splitIndex));

  return merge(leftArray, rightArray);
}


List<Map<String, int>> merge(leftArray, rightArray) {
  List<Map<String, int>> result = [];
  int? i = 0;
  int? j = 0;

  // Search for the smallest eleent in left and right arrays
  // array and insert it into result
  // After the loop only one array has remaining elements
  while(i! < leftArray.length && j! < rightArray.length) {
    if(leftArray[i]['money'] <= rightArray[j]['money']) {
      result.add(leftArray[i]);
      i++;
    } else {
      result.add(rightArray[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }

  // Insert remaining elements of left array into result
  // as long as there are remaining elements
  while(i! < leftArray.length) {
    result.add(leftArray[i]);
    i++;
  }

  // Insert remaining elements of right array into result
  // as long as there are remaining elements
  while(j! < rightArray.length) {
    result.add(rightArray[j]);
    j++;
  }

  return result;
}
```

and then we use it to get purchase list code:

```
final amount = 3500;
final sortedData = mergeSort(data);
// at this point out data is sorted by 'money'

List<Map<String, int>> canBePurchased = [];

for (Map<String, int> item in sortedData) {
  if (item['money']! <= amount) {
    canBePurchased.add(item);
  }
}
print(canBePurchased);

// to get only the last item
if (canBePurchased.isNotEmpty) {
  print(canBePurchased.last);
}
```